# Kinematics of a bar towed from one point

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, simulations

I am trying to implement a rigid bar which is pulled from one end, in Matlab. The initial coordinates of the points are P1(0,0) P2(1,0).

I am using lumped mass model, where the weight is on the particles. The only existing efforts are a vertical effort in P2 and the gravity. The mass of each particle is 0.05.

My code is shown next:

```
 L=1; %length of the bar

Mass1=[1 0; 0 1];
Efforts1=[0; 20-9.8*0.05];

Mass2=[1 0; 0 1];
Efforts2=[0; -9.8*0.05];

acel1=Mass1\Efforts1;

acel2=Mass2\Efforts2;
dt=0.1; %time step


%variables creation
%position of mass1
x1=zeros(100,1); x1(1)=L; x1(2)=L; 
y1=zeros(100,1); 
%position of mass2
x2=zeros(100,1); 
y2=zeros(100,1);
%velocities 
x1_dot=zeros(100,1); y1_dot=zeros(100,1);
x2_dot=zeros(100,1); y2_dot=zeros(100,1);

for i=2:100
   %numerical integration of first mass. Accel, vel, pos
   x1_dot(i)=x1_dot(i-1) + dt*acel1(1);
   y1_dot(i)=y1_dot(i-1) + dt*acel1(2);

   x1(i)=x1(i-1) + dt*x1_dot(i);
   y1(i)=y1(i-1) + dt*y1_dot(i);

   %numerical integration of first mass. Accel, vel, pos
   x2_dot(i)=x2_dot(i-1) + dt*acel2(1);
   y2_dot(i)=y2_dot(i-1) + dt*acel2(2);

   x2(i)=x2(i-1) + dt*x2_dot(i);
   y2(i)=y2(i-1) + dt*y2_dot(i);

   if y2(i)<0
       y2(i)=0;
   end

   X=[x1 x2]; Y=[y1 y2];
   plot(X,Y); hold on;
   pause(0.1);

 end
```

I think that the right point is ok, however, don't know how to make that the bar lengths remain constant. What must I do with left point?

Comment: Please see [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5604/84967) on questions about Computational physics. Thank you.

Comment: Conceptually if you are modelling the particles in the bar, it's not rigid, it's deformable? If you want the bar to stay together you have to model the bonding between the particles.

Comment: Does this mean that x1 is the only particle subjected to forces, and that x2 and the rest are L*cos(alpha)?